# How can I tell if an element has re-rendered or not in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, performance-testing, reactive-programming

What is a simple method of determining whether or not a component has been re-rendered in VueJS?

EDIT: I found the best answer to this question is to use the `beforeUpdate()` lifecycle hook as it is called whenever the data changes on your component and the DOM re-renders.

```
  beforeUpdate () {
console.log('Re-render', new Date())
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to dump the current date in a pair of mustache braces:

```
<div>{{ new Date }}</div>
```

If it changes, you know it was re-rendered.